# Angular adding items to base class template from child class?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base component with its own template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-base',
  templateUrl: './base.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base.css']
})
export class BaseComponent  {}
```

I want to inherit the base component and its html however I need to add some buttons on the page that are not on the base component. How can I do that?

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-popup',
      templateUrl: './base.html', <-- Need to add the below buttons to this
       <div mat-dialog-actions>
           <button mat-raised-button class="btn-primary" (click)="cancel()">Close</button>    
       </div>

      styleUrls: ['./base.css']
    })

export class PopupComponent extends BaseComponent  {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never heard about inheritance in component templates. But you can make a generic template, which will depend on components Input.
Something like this:

```
  @Component({
      selector: 'app-popup',
      templateUrl: './base.html', <-- Need to add the below buttons to this
       <div mat-dialog-actions>
           <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="isCancelEnabled" class="btn-primary" (click)="cancel()">Close</button>    
       </div>

      styleUrls: ['./base.css']
    })

export class PopupComponent extends BaseComponent  {
@Input() isCancelEnabled: boolean = false;
}
```

Or you can use ng-content. Or you can give to @Input some array with data for buttons.